# Sidekiq Jobs maximum run time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am having a job which takes more than 1 hour to execute.Due to that,remaining jobs gets enqueued and not able to start.So I have decided to set maximum run time for background jobs.Is there any way to set timeout for jobs in sidekiq?

Comment: Why don't you use multiple queues? one for those long running jobs and one for the rest https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options. I mean, it doesn't sound right to kill a job that's taking too long if it's actually doing what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot timeout or stop jobs in Sidekiq. This is dangerous and can corrupt your application data.

Sounds like you only have one Sidekiq process with concurrency of 1. You can start multiple Sidekiq processes and they will work on different jobs and you can increase concurrency to do the same.